# Where did dedicated.abac.net. come from in my rDNS and PTR records?

Tags: domain-name-system, reverse-dns, ptr-record

So I followed this guide to the letter: http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/WHMDocs/RdnsForBind

I did so for 3 domains.

When I "test" the records and enter: `host 64.150.176.81` on my linux machine, it shows me `81.172.150.64.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer 64-150-172-81.dedicated.abac.net.`

when it should be showing me `81.176.150.64.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer 64-150-172-81.example.com.`

Has anybody encountered a similar problem?

I am hosting with codero, not abac.net btw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To set the PTR record for your IP address, you *also* need to have the DNS server for that range delegated to your nameserver.

Currently, `abac.net` hold the ownership of your IP address, so you will need to contact them to ask them to configure the nameserver for your IP address to point to your nameserver, or, ask them to change the PTR record to `64-150-172-81.example.com`. Most providers will do one of these for their business customers.

Comment: According to whois, Codero actually "own" that netblock.

Comment: I changed the netblock slightly for security reasons ;)

Comment: Thanks guys, you all are geniuses. Where else could I ask such an obscure question at midnight EST and get an answer in 2 hours? Thank you.

Comment: @dark - it was just after lunch time when I answered that ;) the joys of a worldwide Internet.